# Form fires every time Website is Accessed

Tags: php, jquery, forms

My website has a form that fires every time the website is accessed. It's still in testing phases so I get over 100 BLANK emails a day just from refreshing the page (and yes, all of the inputs are required). The tricky part is that I have a jquery script included. The script fires when you hit the submit button: it then refreshes the page and scrolls down (using a hashtag) to below my form with a message that basically says "thanks for emailing me!"

My code is posted below, but what I need to know is why I keep getting these blank emails even when the input fields are required! I am still very very new to php and jquery.

```
<?php 
$to = 'design@carolbarone.com' ;  
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ; 
$name = $_POST['name'] ; 
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$text = $_POST['message'] ;

$message = "From: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $text \n";

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message) ; 
if($sent) {
  echo ""; 
}else{
  echo ""; 
}
?>
      <form data-abide name="input" action="index.php#hashtag" method="Post" id="theForm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-10">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns name-field">
                <input type="text" name="name" required id="right-label" placeholder="Name">
                <small class="error">Name is required.</small> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns email-field">
                <input type="email" name="email" required id="right-label" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                <small class="error">An email address is required.</small> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                <input type="text" name="subject" required id="right-label" placeholder="Subject">
                <small class="error">A subject is required.</small> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" rows="4" required></textarea>
                <small class="error">A message is required.</small> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
        <div class="success_message">
          <h3>Thank you for your message!</h3>
          <p>Your email has been sent successfully and I appreciate you getting in touch with me. I will be sending a reply soon.</p>
        </div>

      <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
if(window.location.hash == '#hashtag') { 
    $('.success_message').show();       
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#theForm').offset().top }, 1000); 
}
});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You never bothered fencing off your code to check if a form submission was actually performed, so the code will fire EVERY time the page is loaded. You'd want something at least like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... handle form ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're required on the browser side, but you have no server-side validation. Older browsers that don't respect HTML5's `required` attribute, bots, etc. will happily submit all day long.

At its simplest, just check that there's data in each field:

```
$to = 'design@carolbarone.com' ;  
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ; 
$name = $_POST['name'] ; 
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$text = $_POST['message'] ;

$message = "From: $name \nEmail: $email \nMessage: $text \n";

if($subject && $name && $email && $text) {
  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message) ; 
  ...
```

You'd want to do more validation (like making sure `$email` is a valid format) but this'll at least prevent blank ones. Of note: your form is vulnerable to header injection. Using a proper library like SwiftMailer will make coding email easier as well as protecting you from malicious spambots somewhat.

As Marc B notes, by including the mailing code on the same page as the form, you're firing it whenever someone accesses that page. Typically, your POST handling should be in a different file/route.

Comment: Nah, I always put my POST handling at the top of the same page, because (a) it's much more convenient if you want to display an error after submission, (b) all your code is in the same file, and (c) you don't have to worry about anybody surfing directly to the processing URL.

Comment: @Blazemonger If you're using files, perhaps, but in a proper framework like Laravel you'd have a controller with functions handling the GET and the POST and routes pointing at each. They'd be next to each other, but with proper logical separation.

Comment: Obviously -- but neither I nor (it would appear) OP are using such a framework.

Comment: @Blazemonger OP would probably benefit from one. :-/

Comment: Now you're just being elitist. Never use a sledgehammer to swat a fly. However, you have a point about using something like Swift Mailer to provide added security.

Comment: A framework's going to provide routing, validation, etc. that are highly beneficial. I disagree that something like Laravel is a sledgehammer, but even if it were, a sledgehammer is still better than a squirt gun at the task.

Comment: Hi! I added what Marc B noted, and it stopped firing (phew!). I have also added what you noted.

As for changing my post handling, I'm not sure how to do that part. Originally I used:

    action="submitform.php"

which had all of my php in it. When I needed to add the jquery, it didnt work. So i added the php to my index and changed it to the current

    action="index.php#hashtag"

Is there a better way to do this that I am so obviously missing (again)?